# CPC template incompatiable with newest TeXLive by breaking `\@pushfilename`

Tags: hyperref

[The CPC template](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-file-manager/file/5eb95eb34c50b72af111ee82) changes the definition of `\@pushfilename` and hence becomes incompatible with `hypperref`.

Now that I have already located the question, I cannot make any change to the template file. (In the minimal example, this is surrounded by `% I cannot change the ... code`.) Therefore I have to finish the bugfix via commands outside it.

Can I finish this task, or is it a impossible mission?

The closest problem, to my best effort, is [Latex continuous table numbering and \tbl macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586445/latex-continuous-table-numbering-and-tbl-macro/586495#586495). (I hope this will make some help.)

---

Here is the minimal example, where I have already moved the class contents into the main file:

```
%% This is file `cpc.cls'
%% Version 1.0
%% CUP Journal - Combinatorics, Probability and Computing (CPC) document class
%% Copyright 2018 Cambridge University Press
% \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% \ProvidesClass{cpc}[2020/04/17 v1.0 CUP CPC LaTeX document class]

% This is file `cpcguide.tex`
% v1.0, released 31 Jan 2019
% Copyright 2019 Cambridge University Press

% I cannot change the following code
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@pushfilename{%
  \xdef\@currnamestack{%
    {\@currname}%
    {\@currext}%
    {\the\catcode`\@}%
    \@currnamestack}}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
%  I cannot change the above code

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Here is the compile log (Only the first 6 errors are copied.)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.11.4)  9 NOV 2022 19:29
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**CPCguide.tex
(./CPCguide.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex
/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2022-02-21 v7.00n Hypertext links for LaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)

! LaTeX hooks Error: Extra \PopDefaultHookLabel.
(hooks)              This command will be ignored.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.107 \RequirePackage{ltxcmds}[2010/11/12]
                                          

LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.

Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.


! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.175 \def\Hy@@VersionCheck #1#2 #3 #4\@nil
                                           {%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.175 \def\Hy@@VersionCheck #1#2 #3 #4\@nil
                                           {%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \@empty \def \MessageBreak...
l.175 \def\Hy@@VersionCheck #1#2 #3 #4\@nil
                                           {%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                     \endgroup 
l.175 \def\Hy@@VersionCheck #1#2 #3 #4\@nil
                                           {%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.175 \def\Hy@@VersionCheck #1#2 #3 #4\@nil
                                           {%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

<Some lines are omitted here since the log is too long.>
........................
........................
........................
<Some lines are omitted here since the log is too long.>
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5680 strings out of 478268
 85445 string characters out of 5846353
 371147 words of memory out of 5000000
 23901 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,0n,84p,189b,44s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: complain to the authors of the template.